# Multiple simultaneous access to file write in node.js gives file write error

Tags: node.js, file-io

I am using following code to write into a common file.

```
fs.appendFile('log.txt', str, function (err) {
    console.log("error writing file");
  });
```

It is called at same time from multiple function calls. It completes file write operation correctly but still throws error "error writing file."

What is clean way to write/execute this code. I want each call to wait for I/O operation till already writing function finishes the job.

Comment: why not have a single log function that handles all the writes?

Comment: I want all data to be written in same file. How do I handle it?

Comment: Hey fixed. I used appenFileSync function. Thanks anyways!!!!

Comment: You should avoid Sync IO, it prevent node.js from handling anything else during that time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a basic example of a logging module.

```
var fs = require('fs');

var logStream = fs.createWriteStream('log.txt', {flags:'a'});

function log (str) {
  logStream.write(str);
}

module.exports = log;
```

Answer (score 8):

Actually you are missing an if - you should check if err is set.

```
fs.appendFile('log.txt', str, function (err) {
    if (err) console.log("error writing file");
  });
```

Otherwise it will simply output your message because the callback is called after every append.